# How does object instantiation works for Interface

Tags: java

So I have some fundamental gap in understanding.

I create Path object - Path p = Paths.get("/");

So Path is interface thereby it cannot be instantiated. But Paths.get() method has Path return type. I know it is common practice to use interface object reference. But how does it work under the hood? I thought it creates some anonymous class implementing Path interface. But the I tried to invoke .getClass() method on Path object and it returned: class sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.

Please explain briefly how does it work.

Comment: nvm figured out

Comment: Paths is not an interface (note Paths vs Path). You call a static .get() method that returns an object that implement the Path interface.

Comment: You need to know about [Anonymous Classes][1].

By concept there is an actual class involved.


  [1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: *"I thought it creates some anonymous class implementing Path interface"* — It doesn't have to be anonymous.

Comment: @nos yep, should've go deeper. I see it invokes of() method eventually and it returns concrete class object - UnixPath in my case (Mac OS)